# d3 v4 brush extent Error: <rect> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to follow this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

I think the problem is setting the extent of the `brushX`, following in an error for the rect overlay and selection.

Here is my code, almost copied from the example:

```
var brush = d3.brushX()
                .extent([0,0],[brushChart.width,brushChart.height])
                .on("brush end",brushed);
context = svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "context")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + brushMargin.left + "," + brushMargin.top + ")");
context.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "brush")
                    .call(brush) //this throws errors
```

the errors are at the line "call(brush):

[image: errors]

I already tried to select the rect and add the values like in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/AMDS/57e1daf9d5ef60b124d9).

Comment: How do you calculate `brushChart.width` and height? Perhaps you can provide a jsfiddle or a plunkr?

Comment: I set it in a variable: var brushChart = {width:500,height:500}; I provide a jsfiddle as soon as I can.

Comment: `NaN` is returned in javascript when either `parseInt()` or `parseFloa()t` is called and it was unable to turn a string into a number. Your error is basically saying, hey I expected a number (`length`) but got `NaN` so where it's calculating `length` you must be passing an invalid string can't be parsed into a number.

Comment: yeah that is the problem, altocumulus found my error..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initialization of your brush contains an error. When calling [`brush.extent()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/README.md#brush_extent) you need to specify an *array* of points, i.e. an array of arrays (nested array):

> [#](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/README.md#brush_extent) *brush*.**extent**([*extent*]) [<>](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/src/brush.js#L521)
>
> If extent is specified, sets the brushable extent to the specified array of points [[*x0, y0*], [*x1, y1*]]

Thus, your intialization becomes

```
var brush = d3.brushX()
                .extent([[0,0],[brushChart.width,brushChart.height]]) // [[x0,y0], [x1,y1]]
                .on("brush end",brushed);
```

Comment: thank you very much, unbelievable how I missed both from the example and both from the documentation.. sometimes not to doing copy and paste does not help..:)